# Can't get a custom Membership Provider to work with Sitecore 6

Tags: asp.net-membership, sitecore, sitecore6, sqlmembershipprovider

I followed the directions in the Membership Providers document provided by Sitecore, but I was unable to get my membership provider to work correctly.

Specifically, in the web.config, I changed the "realProviderName" attribute on the sitecore provider to point to my provider.  However, this didn't do anything.

I realized that the "defaultProvider" attribute was set to the "switcher" provider, so I changed that to point directly at my provider, and it worked, but I'm not sure if I'm causing problems elsewhere by doing this...

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you probably want to do is set the `defaultProvider="sitecore"` then on the provider named `sitecore` change the `realProviderName` to be the name of your custom provider. The switcher is used if you want to house a certain domain (i.e. `extranet`) in a different membership database.

I found [that the example Sitecore gives in their docs](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/membership_providers_a4.pdf#page=14) for this does indeed work.